# Is it possible to print field values if a junit test fails?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I just now started using junit/unit tests facilities. And now I feel what goodness it is :) Is it possible to print field values if a junit test fails?

My method try implement INT(A(D — B)^C):

```
public static int countFieldEventPoints(PointsCountingTableRow row,float centimetres){
    float temp = row.getA()*(float)Math.pow((centimetres - row.getB()),row.getC());
    return roundUP(temp);
}
```

My test:

```
public void testCountlongJumpEventPoints(){
    PointsCountingTableRow row = Tables.get2001table().getLongJump();
    float cm = 736f;
    assertEquals(900,PointCounterService.countFieldEventPoints(row,cm));
}
```

console print:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :900
Actual   :901
```

round up method (I feel there is the problem):

```
private static int roundUP(double floatNumber){
    return (int) Math.round(floatNumber + .5);
}
```

row class:

```
public class PointsCountingTableRow {
private float A;
private float B;
private float C;


public PointsCountingTableRow(float a, float b, float c) {
    A = a;
    B = b;
    C = c;
}

public float getA() {
    return A;
}

public float getB() {
    return B;
}

public float getC() {
    return C;
}
```

}

Comment: Use `Math.ceil(double)` if you want to round up. You are right that 0 + 0.5 rounded up is 1.

Comment: I don't like hit and run down voters either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Unit Testing :) For the sake of code covering, it's a good practice to code a set of test methods for each public method in your API: one for each interesting case, including successful and failing tests (thanks to Florian Schaetz).

What to do then, whith *private* methods (as `roundUP`) ? They also deserve a test battery, which you can easily design after a simple refactorizing of your API:

- Create a new "helper" class with package (default) access, and a private constructor. This class will contain just public static methods.
- Move `roundUP` from its actual container class to the helper class, and make it public.
- Create a public tester class, *in the same package* (thus granting it access to the helper class), and fullfil it with the necessary testing methods.

Back to your case, you can code several testing methods to benchmark `roundUP` properly: I suggest ten methods: `roundUP(0.0)`, `roundUP(0.1)`,  `roundUP(0.2)` ... `roundUP(0.9)`.

As part of the Test Driven Development, every time a new error in your program is reported, you must then code a new tester method to *reproduce such an error*. Then, fix the bug until all the testers work OK (the new and the existing ones): In this way the test battery will *grow* and make sure that no updates nor fixes will accidentally break the existing behaviour.

---

Is it possible to print row fields values if test fall?

Of corse. You can program your testing methods to react in case of fail, in this way:

```
@Test
public void myTest()
{
    // Prepare the input parameters:
    PointsCountingTableRow row=...
    float centimetres=...

    // Perform the test:
    int result=countFieldEventPoints(row, centimeters);

    // Check the results:
    String messageInCaseOfFail="row="+row.toString();
    assertEquals(messageInCaseOfFail, expectedResult, result);
}
```

Or also through the `fail` methd:

```
@Test
public void myTest()
{
    // Prepare the input parameters:
    ...

    // Perform the test:
    try
    {
       int result=countFieldEventPoints(row, centimeters);
       // Check the results:
       assert...
    }
    catch (SomeException e)
    {
        fail(messsageInCaseOfFail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks of a suggestion, what about print `raw` values in the test console if test fail?

Comment: A single test for each public method? Sounds strange, I would code a single test for each branch in each public method. For example, if my method should throw an exception for a certain invalid parameter, I create a test method for that. If it should return a certain result for a certain valid parameter, I write a test method for that, etc.etc.

Comment: @Florian Schaetz You are right. That's much better explained. I've updated my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to print field values if a test fails?

Of course it is.  However, I wouldn't recommend doing that.  Instead, if a unit test fails, and you can't see why it is happening by looking at the code, then I would recommend that you do the following:

- run the failing test in your IDE's debugger,
- set a breakpoint at the appropriate point, and
- use the debugger UI to examine the state of the objects and variables directly.

I'd only implement diagnostic (e.g. display) code in a unit test suite in particularly complicated cases.

Adding diagnostic code to a unit test only increases the volume of code that needs to be read and maintained.  Besides, it is only necessary for a test that fails ... and that is a scenario that you are aiming to eliminate.